# Style is not applied on HTML element

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I use vue2 in my project.

I have property img_path and class txt-disabled:

```
<script> 
  export default {
    props: {
      img_path: { required: false },
      title: { required: false }
    },
    components: {  },
    computed: {},
    methods: {},
  };
</script>

<style>  
  .txt-disabled{
    color:lightgray;
  } 
</style>
```

when property is empty I want to apply txt-disabled css class on span the element:

```
 <span :class="{ img_path: txt-disabled }">{{title}}</span>
```

But on example above txt-disabled class not applied.

Any idea why class not applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put css class as the key, and the condition as value, see [example here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax):

```html
<span :class="{ 'txt-disabled': !img_path }">{{title}}</span>
```

Comment: It should be noted that `img_path` will always be `truthy` given the code shown since it's a non-null object.